# GPA calculator that discriminates science vs non-science courses

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to write a GPA calculator that can also discriminate science vs non-science GPAs.  One column (A) has class abbreviations (MA=math, etc).  So, I want to sum the grade credits (column D) overall (which I've done) and also based on whether courses are science (coded BI, CH, MA or PC) or non-science all other.  For the science GPA, the latest attempt is:

=SUMIF(A:A,OR("MA","PC","BI","CH"),D:D)

Know OR won't work on text like this, but shows best what I'm trying to do.  Also tried SUMIF and other things.  Any suggestions?
Thanks, Jim

Answer (score 0):

Two options - a filtered pivot table or a helper column.

Create a pivot table with your data. By selecting "Course" as the rows, and "Credits" as the values, you could get a very simple pivot table which will give you the total.

Alternatively, you could create a helper column using `=if(OR(A2="MA",A2="PC",A2="BI",A2="CH"),"Science","Humanities")` which would give the result "Science" for science courses. You could then use `[=Sumif(E:E,"Science",D:D)]*`  to work out the credits.

<sub>* N:B this assumes you have the helper column at location E:E)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

1. Enter into E1 (Science GPA):

   ```
   = SUMIF(A:A, "MA", D:D) + SUMIF(A:A, "PC", D:D) 
   + SUMIF(A:A, "BI", D:D) + SUMIF(A:A, "CH", D:D)
   ```
2. Enter into E2 (Humanities GPA):

   ```
   =SUM(A:A) - E1
   ```